# Bringing Back Distinct Values From Tuple

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics, tuples

Hi I am populating a menu with dynamic data from a tuple to a list.  I am having problems bringing back distinct values though.  Instead of my tuple bringing back 3 items as it should it's bring back it's bringing the items back 8 times.  I am unsure what I'm doing wrong?  I'm using C#.  I think the problem maybe with the line of code below:

```
var attributeByCategory = customAttributes.Select(a => a.Item2).Where(b => b.Attribute.CategoryId == categoryTuple.AttributeCategoryId).Distinct();
```

I'm posting the rest of my code below.  If anyone could help me with this it would be very helpful.  I'm brand new to using generics.

```
protected void createFilter(int categoryid)
{
    // check cateogyrid 

    //get list of proudct id
    List<int> productIds = new List<int>();
    DataRow[] productRow = CategoriesProductsData.Tables["Products"].Select("Category_ID = " + 573);

    productIds = productRow.Select(p => int.Parse(p["Product_ID"].ToString())).ToList();

    //get attributes
    ITCProductService pService = new TCProductServiceClient();
    var productTuples = (pService.GetProductsAttributes(productIds));

    List<Tuple<int, CustomAttribute>> customAttributes = new List<Tuple<int, CustomAttribute>>();
    foreach (var productTuple in productTuples)
    {
        foreach (var attributeTuple in productTuple.m_Item2)
        {
            var customAttribute = new Tuple<int, CustomAttribute>(productTuple.m_Item1, new CustomAttribute(attributeTuple));
            customAttributes.Add(customAttribute);
        }
    }

    List<CustomAttributeCategory> categories = new List<CustomAttributeCategory>();

    var categoryTuples = customAttributes.Select(a => a.Item2).Select(a => a.Attribute.Category).Distinct();

    foreach (var categoryTuple in categoryTuples)
    {
        var category = new CustomAttributeCategory(categoryTuple);

        var attributeByCategory = customAttributes.Select(a => a.Item2).Where(b => b.Attribute.CategoryId == categoryTuple.AttributeCategoryId).Distinct();
        foreach (var attributeTuple in attributeByCategory)
        {
            var attribute = new CustomAttribute(attributeTuple.Attribute);
            var attributeProductIds = customAttributes.Where(a => a.Item2.Attribute.AttributeId == attributeTuple.Attribute.AttributeId).Select(a => a.Item1).ToList();
            attribute.ProductIds = attributeProductIds;


            category.Attributes.Add(attribute);
        }
        categories.Add(category);            

      }


    foreach (var cat in categories)
    {
        var itemCategory = new RadMenuItem(cat.Category.Name.ToString());
        handsetMenu.Items.Add(itemCategory);

        foreach (var attr in cat.Attributes)
        {
            itemCategory.Items.Add(new RadMenuItem(attr.Attribute.Value));
        }
    }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is unrelated but you should refactor your code so that each inested foreach is in a method it would be easier to read and easier to debug.

Comment: @johnny5 Thanks for the tip.  I tried to put my second foreach in it's own method GetAttr() and then call it inside my first foreach, but I'm using the variable cat in both foreach loops.  I'm not sure how that works?

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated but try to refactor the methods like this it will make it more readable I'll try to figure out your issue in the mean time:

```
List<Tuple<int, CustomAttribute>> customAttributes = GetCustomAttrubutes(productTuples)

protected List<Tuple<int, CustomAttribute>> GetCustomAttrubutes([ProductTuplesType] productTuples)
{
    foreach (var productTuple in productTuples)
    {
       foreach (var attributeTuple in productTuple.m_Item2)
        {
            var customAttribute = new Tuple<int, CustomAttribute>(productTuple.m_Item1, new CustomAttribute(attributeTuple));
            customAttributes.Add(customAttribute);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

There is a lot going on in your code and with out the data your using I can only make a guess.

Your doing a distinct on the whole tuple instead of just the CategoryId, you might want to use a `distinctby(b => b.Attribute.CategoryId)` from   [MoreLinq](http://morelinq.googlecode.com)

**EDIT**
      To help understand this and other developers understand this you should switch to using proper models ie.

```
public class Products {
   public int id;
   public List<Attributes> Atrributes
}

public class Attributes {
   public int id;
   public string Name;
}
```

this will make more sense when debugging and improve readability

Comment: I'm trying this:  var attributeByCategory = customAttributes.Select(a => a.Item2).DistinctBy(b => b.Attribute.CategoryId);   But I'm getting an error on DistinctBy, it says 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CustomAttribute>' does not contain a definition for 'DistinctBy' and no extension method 'DistinctBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CustomAttribute>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yeah you need to install more linq to provide the Distinct by function.  Here is the nuget install link to run in the nuget console `Install-Package morelinq -Version 1.1.1` or you can click the link i provided above

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing your data but my guess is that when your doing distinct your although your item2 is the same your item1 is different so it returns all the results.  Distinctby should take care of that but if thats not the case can you post a snap shot of all the results being returned

Comment: I added a screen shot of what I'm getting back.  The menu items are repeating over and over again, and each of the root menu items have the same attributes under them, when they should have only the attributes that go with that root item.  Something changed though, before it was repeating all of the attributes over and over again.

Comment: I added a second screen shot.  In this screen shot it's bringing back everything that I need to come back, but everything is duplicated.

Comment: I see the snapshot I mean the snapshot from the locals window, but lets try this differently what results are you trying to get exactly?